# How to display nested JSON array element in View controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

When I try to display author's name in tableview cell I am getting error like "Cannot assign value of type [String] to type String" as I declared authors element as an array. As the API response of author element is an array, I am not sure how to declare it.Please help me on this

API response

```
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 2361,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "_eyJAAAAQBAJ",
      "etag": "MJbx6HKC3B4",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "A Quilting Life",
        "subtitle": "Creating a Handmade Home",
        **"authors": [
          "Sherri McConnell"
        ],**
        "publisher": "C&T Publishing Inc",
        "publishedDate": "2013-02-12",

struct VolumeInfo : Codable {
    
    let authors : [String]
    let publisher : String?
    let subtitle : String?
    let title : String?

}
```

code :

```
class MainVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
   
    var items : [Items] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.jpeg")!)
        fetchBooks { data in
            self.items.self = data
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.bookTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell",for:indexPath) as! BookCell
        cell.bookAuthor.text = items[indexPath.row].volumeInfo.title
        cell.bookCategory.text = items[indexPath.row].volumeInfo.publisher
        cell.bookAuthor.text = items[indexPath.row].volumeInfo.authors
        return cell
    }
    
    func fetchBooks(comp : @escaping ([Items])->()){
        
        let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=quilting"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
         
         guard url != nil else {
             return
         }
         let session = URLSession.shared
         
         let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { [self] (data, response, error) in
             //check for errors
             if error == nil && data != nil{
           
                 //parse json
                 
                 do {
                     let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data!)
                    comp(result.items)
                    
                     print("Retrieved books are \(items)")
                 }
                 catch {
                     print("Error in json parcing\(error)")
                 }
             }
         }
         //make api call
         dataTask.resume()
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'Book' come from?

Answer (score 1):

`text` expects a string, `authors` is an array of string. This is a type mismatch what the error clearly states.

A solution is to `join` the array

```
cell.bookAuthor.text = items[indexPath.row].volumeInfo.authors.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Side note:

Getting the same value again and again is unnecessarily expensive. A better way is

```
let info = items[indexPath.row].volumeInfo
cell.bookAuthor.text = info.title
cell.bookCategory.text = info.publisher
cell.bookAuthor.text = info.authors.joined(separator: ", ")
```